# How to verify password generated by password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

Tags: php, hash, passwords

`password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`
function to store the user inserted password in to mysql database but
when i try to check login using

```
$verify_password=password_verify ($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

it show me error so anyone tell me what is the error. in passwordverify php function the default parameter like `password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )` what is $hash in this.

Comment: Hash is what `password_hash` gave you..

Comment: actually i used default hash function ie 
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); so can you tell me what is hash in this senario.

Comment: `password_hash` __returns__ the hash, you do save this hash to the database, right?

Comment: yes but i want to check login later i used password_verify ($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT); where i wrong please suggest if you have any idea.

Comment: You need to pass the __hash__ created by `password_hash` as second argument to `password_verify`. Read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: can you suggest me what is my $hash in my senario i used simply password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); to store the password so when i check login using                                 password_verify ($password,$hash); so what is my $hash.

Comment: Show a a bit more of your login code, like how you retrieve the stored hash from the database

Comment: `$hash` is what you have stored in the database.

Comment: this is my controller code.                                                                                      public function userLogin()
 {
  $email=$this->input->post('email');
  $password=$this->input->post('password');
  $password_hash=password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $verify_password=password_verify ($password,$password_hash);
  $userData=array('email'=>$email,'password'=>$verify_password,'status'=>'1');
  $res=$this->Main_model->checkLogin($userData);
  if($res)
  {
   echo "Sucess";
  }
  else
  {
   echo "login faild";
  }
 }

Comment: any idea  tkaus about this

Answer (score 2):

The parameters you pass to the password_verify() function are wrong. Use the stored hash as the second argument instead:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use password_hash instead of using password_verify.

```
$verify_password=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

**password_hash()** creates a new password hash using a strong one-way hashing algorithm. password_hash() is compatible with crypt(). Therefore, password hashes created by crypt() can be used with password_hash().

The following algorithms are currently supported:

**PASSWORD_DEFAULT** - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

**PASSWORD_BCRYPT** - Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the hash. This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$" identifier. The result will always be a 60 character string, or FALSE on failure.
Supported Options:

- salt  to manually provide a salt to use when hashing the password. Note that this will override and prevent a salt from being automatically generated.

If omitted, a random salt will be generated by password_hash() for each password hashed. This is the intended mode of operation.

- cost which denotes the algorithmic cost that should be used. Examples of these values can be found on the crypt() page.

If omitted, a default value of 10 will be used. This is a good baseline cost, but you may want to consider increasing it depending on your hardware.

Comment: i know this mr. manish ji but my question is only that how may check login